# How do I change font size for Tkinter Scrolling Text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using this code to make a scrolling text window using Tkinter with python 3.5, and I was curious what I could do to change the font size and color of the scrolling text.

```
 import tkinter as tk

 root = tk.Tk()
 deli = 100           # milliseconds of delay per character
 svar = tk.StringVar()
 labl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=svar, height=5)

 def shif():
     shif.msg = shif.msg[1:] + shif.msg[0]
     svar.set(shif.msg)
     root.after(deli, shif)

shif.msg = 'Text example: Blah, Blah Blah'
shif()
labl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.config()` maybe?

Comment: This should be covered in most tkinter tutorials and documentation. Have you done any research before asking?

Comment: Bryan, I have been researching and checking other places for a solution, but none of them seem to work. It has been a while since I programmed with tkinter so I may be implementing the code incorrectly.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, I had typed label.config instead of labl.config, sorry for bothering everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't change the `font-size` of `Scrollbar`, because it doesn't have font-size.

You can change the `font-size` of `Text`. It has a font module.

```
textarea = Text(root, font=("Arial 45"))
```

Comment: This does not work if you have a scrollbar. I tried and found out that changing the font caused the scrollbar disappear.

Answer (score -1):

```
def create_scrolltext(self):
        F_font = ('bold', 30)
        scroll_w = 30
        scroll_h = 10
        scrollText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self, width=scroll_w, height=scroll_h, wrap = tk.WORD, font=F_font)       
        scrollText.grid(column=0, columnspan=3)
```

Comment: Please add some context to make your answer easier to read. Don't just answer with a snippet of code. Especially since `scrolledtext` isn't defined and this seems to be a method on a class (which class?) and how should OP use this in his/her code?

Answer (score -1):

```
def create_scrolltext(self):
    F_font = ('bold', 30)
    scroll_w = 30
    scroll_h = 10
    scrollText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self, width=scroll_w, height=scroll_h, wrap = tk.WORD, font=F_font)
    scrollText.config(bg='white', fg='blue')
    scrollText.grid(column=0, columnspan=3)
```